# Is spiritual realization of advaitin real?

Tags: advaita

Is the realization of an advaitin real? If it is real, it implies duality. Else, what remains? He can't be followed as teacher. As far as I know Gaudapada says there is no realization at all.

What do advaitins think about realization?

Comment: If you are aware of the sensual universe then it is 'real' as you are aware of duality. From the standpoint of Nirguna Brahman, then there is no realization. Gaudapada is speaking from the standpoint of the Absolute, from Nirguna Brahman. You are mixing together two different standpoints together in your question.

Comment: You need to define what is meant by "real".

Comment: I have rarely seen such a confused and confusing question!!

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda so for a realized souls who is realized according to us, there exists nothing real,his view is same as from the standpoint of absolute, is it?

Comment: Because of prArabdha karma, a realized person still moves in this world, even after realization. He sees world as dream.

Comment: It is like asking does God exist?

Comment: If you want to study, the Vedantasaara is an excellent book by Sadananda Yogindra.From sloka 170 onwards you get your answer,Thanks

Answer (score 3):

(https://images.app.goo.gl/KhoTRVvppN1R8pY48)

**Self-realization is real and happens in Turiya.**
Does the dish antennae  look at itself? 
Who is the observer and what is observed? Imagine the observer to be the soul and observed the super soul. Observer is part of the observed. Just like a dish antennae

Relevant Aadi shankara sloka:

> Prátah smarámi hrudi samsphuradátmatattvam
>   saccitsukham paramahamsagatim turèyam
>   yatsvapna jágarasussuptamavaiti nityam
>   tadbrahma niskalamaham na cha bhutasañgha.
>
> At dawn I remember the Reality which is the Self, shining brilliantly in the heart, existence-consciousness-happiness, the goal of Paramahamsasannyasins (sages), **the Fourth**; That which knows always the states of dream, waking and deep-sleep, that Brahman which is partless I am, not the cluster of elements.

Brahman undivided. Observer = minutest part of observed

http://greenmesg.org/stotras/brahman/pratah_smarami.php

Now what about the body? Is that consciousness? It is. 
It is created by the supreme Brahman as an extension to itself to host the individual soul  and gives it experiences or maya to finally see whether the individual soul can realize its true nature.
World is maya  fromYoga vashista section lavanoupagyanam

Comment: You need to cite sources for your answer.